# Prove if the following statement is true or false: *If x is a real number with $x>0$, then $x^2>4$. Suppose $x\leq 2$. Then $x^2 \leq 4$*

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Here I have another question related to rules of inference. It says: using the rules [these rules](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_rules_of_inference#Rules_for_negations) of inference prove if the following statement is true or false:

> *If x is a real number with $x>2$, then $x^2>4$. Suppose $x\leq 2$. Then $x^2 \leq 4$*

My problem is that I do not know what are the logic sentences given here. I thought about "**x is a real number**" being **q**,  "**$x>0$**" being **p**  and **z** may be "$x^2>4$". But next, I do not know what to do with the remaining part. Should I split in two logic sentences $x\leq 2$ or not, and the same for $x^2 \leq 4$? Can you please help me with finding the sentences? Thanks.

Comment: How many examples have you tried?

Comment: First of all I split "Suppose .... $x^2 \leq 4$" in four cases

Comment: Then I thought I should somehow stick them together in logic sentences, so I could use the inference rules, but it was wrong , because after trying to figure out some relations I found none.

Comment: The question as written is wrong. I'd repeat what WillO asked. Did you try examples for $x \le 2$?

Comment: @user21820 So this is my intent, I want to show that it's wrong or true, by using inference rules, not  calculations.

Comment: I suggest you to forget for a moment about the clause : "x is a real number" and assume that the domain of quantification is restricted to the set $\mathbb R$ of *real* numbers. Thus, the argument to be assessed is : 1) $x > 2 \rightarrow x^2 > 4$; 2) $x \le 2$; 3) $x^2 \le 4$. I assume that you are asked to prove   if the argument is valid, i.e. if, 3) follows from 1) and 2).

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Thank you, but it is still not what I want. I do not want to use calculation, or look at inequalities, I want to somehow find what are the logic sentences and arrange them in implications, or other forms using boolean algebra. The problem is, if I try to make notations for this 4 statements, then I do not get anything.

Comment: So the answer seems to be that the number of examples you've tried is zero?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can try modelling the problem with propositional logic.

Let :

> $p$ is $x>2$ and $q$ is $x^2 > 4$.

Thus, $\lnot p$ is $x \le 2$ and $\lnot q$ is $x^2 \le 4$.

The problem asks to assess if the argument :

> **if** $(p \rightarrow q)$ **and** $\lnot p$, **then** $\lnot q$.

In order for $\lnot p$ to be $TRUE$, we have that $p$ must be $FALSE$.

With $p$ FALSE, the conditional $p \rightarrow q$ is $TRUE$, either when $q$ is $TRUE$ or when $q$ is $FALSE$ (see truth-table for $\rightarrow$).

In conclusion, the two *premises* $p \rightarrow q$ and $\lnot p$ do not "force us" to have $q$ $TRUE$ and the argument is *invalid*.

We have here an example of the fallacy called : [Denying the antecedent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denying_the_antecedent).

---

A simple example showing it is obtained assuming $x = -3$.

Our $p$ is $-3 > 2$, which is $FALSE$, and $q$ is $-3^2=9 \ge 4$ is $TRUE$; thus ($FALSE \rightarrow TRUE$ is $TRUE$) : $p \rightarrow q$ is $TRUE$.

But when $p$ is $-3 > 2$, $\lnot p$ is $-3 \le 4$, which is $TRUE$; thus, both premises are $TRUE$ with $x = -3$.

But $\lnot q$ is $-3^2=9 \le 4$ is clearly $FALSE$.

---

Alternatively, we can consider the "compound" statement :

> **if** $(p \rightarrow q)$ **and** $\lnot p$, **then** $\lnot q$

as a single propositional formula :

> $((p \rightarrow q) \land \lnot p) \rightarrow \lnot q$;

the counter-example above shows that it is **not** a *tautology*.